# How to install Subversion Ruby bindings on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, svn

I have been looking everywhere to find out how to install the Subversion Ruby bindings but have not came across anything that has helped. Everything has been really old and didn't work.

I  tried:

```
sudo apt-get install libsvn-ruby1.8
```

This installs as expected but returned the following errors:

```
chris@chris-VirtualBox:/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0$ irb
1.8.7 :001 > require 'svn/client'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- svn/client
    from /home/chris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/chris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from (irb):1
    from /home/chris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

when I run:

```
require 'svn/client'
```

Comment: "Fails" usually means error messages and those are really important to diagnosing this problem. Have you tried instead installing this as a gem?

Comment: Sorry about that i edited the post. I don't believe they can be installed using a gem from what I have read. The purpose of installing theses bindings is to use a gem called svn_wc. On the gems github page it says to install the bindings as I mentioned. I will leave a link here incase you can spot something. https://github.com/dvwright/svn_wc

Comment: You can't really mix 1.8.7 bindings with a 2.3.0 ABI.

Comment: You seem to run Ruby 1.8.7 which is really old. Also SVN is not very common in Ruby-Land anymore so I would not expect a well maintained SVN gem for ruby. What do you want to achieve? Perhaps a simple shell-out to the svn library can do the job already?

Comment: It is for use in my rails application. I want a user to be able to enter a svn url, username and password into the web front and the gem to download the repository.